# position of a slider thumb on input slider using pure javascript

Tags: javascript, html

```html
<td>
  <div id="fpscount" style="margin-left: 70px; margin-top: -4px; position:absolute;">15</div>
  <input type="range" name="FPS" min="1" max="60" value="15" id="FPS" class="Slide" onchange="window.status=this.value; Update(this.value);" />
</td>
```

I have a input slider (`type="range"`) in my HTML5 page. Wherein `onchange` event I update the value of a div using innerHTML. Now I want this div whose `position` is set to `absolute` to move with the slider thumb. I have set the slider and thumb styling using CSS and it works perfectly cross browser.

Can I get the slider thumb position using pure javascript? I don't want to use jQueryUI slider as I already have my slider in the HTML page. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: http://www.schillmania.com/content/projects/javascript-animation-1/ here is some explanation about javascript animation

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Calculate the width of the slider and assign the same width to the div.
Now set the position of the div relative to the input.As you move on the slider, calculate the width by which the slider is moved and assign the position of the div by that width.

-Cheers.Happy Coding :)

Comment: thanks bhanu.It worked like a charm :)..god bless ya

Comment: I'm not going to upvote this. you should show some code instead of just telling how to do it.